# Convert/Export C# datalist control/(html page) as a pdf

Tags: c#, asp.net, export, pdf-generation, datalist

I want create a button option that takes the entire datalist and converts it to a pdf file. As anyone done this in asp.net ? Please can you show an example or direct me in the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found a snippet of code a guy posted in forum, and though i might share with others

Re: EXPORT DATAGRID TO PDF in C#/Asp.Net

```
//*************************************************
// 
// Author:
//  Ryan Van Aken (vanakenr@msn.com)
// (C) 2009 Ryan Van Aken
// 
//
// Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining
// a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the
// "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including
// without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish,
// distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to
// permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to
// the following conditions:
// 
// The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be
// included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
// 
// THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND,
// EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF
// MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND
// NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE
// LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION
// OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION
// WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
//
//*************************************************



//SQL Connection Settings -----------
public string strConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BLAH-Here"].ConnectionString;
//-----------------------------------

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//Grab the same data as the datagrid [report view] on the reporting page
//Then set the "ContentType" to "application/vnd.ms-excel" which will generate the .XSL file

//---Retrieve the Report from SQL, drop into DataSet, then Bind() it to a DataGrid
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConn);
conn.Open();
SqlDataAdapter cmd1 = new SqlDataAdapter("EXEC [dbo].[spStatReport] @CompanyID=" + Session["CompanyID"] + ", @StatReportID=" + Request.QueryString["ReportID"].ToString() + ", @StartDate='" + Request.QueryString["StartDate"].Replace("-", "/").ToString() + "', @EndDate='" + Request.QueryString["EndDate"].Replace("-", "/").ToString() + "';", conn);
cmd1.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
DataSet dsReports = new DataSet("tblReporting");
cmd1.Fill(dsReports);
conn.Close();

DataGrid dtaFinal = new DataGrid();
dtaFinal.DataSource = dsReports.Tables[0];
dtaFinal.DataBind();

dtaFinal.HeaderStyle.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
dtaFinal.HeaderStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkGray;
dtaFinal.ItemStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
dtaFinal.AlternatingItemStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.AliceBlue;


//---Create the File---------
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ClearHeaders();

//---For PDF uncomment the following lines----------
//Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
//Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=FileName.pdf");

//---For MS Excel uncomment the following lines----------
//Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
//Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=FileName.xls");

//---For MS Word uncomment the following lines----------
//Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.word";
//Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=FileName.doc");

//---For CSV uncomment the following lines----------
//Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
//Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=FileName.csv");

//---For TXT uncomment the following lines----------
//Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
//Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=FileName.txt");


EnableViewState = false;

StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

//---Renders the DataGrid and then dumps it into the HtmlTextWriter Control
dtaFinal.RenderControl(hw);

//---Utilize the Response Object to write the StringWriter to the page
Response.Write(sw.ToString());
Response.Flush();
Response.Close();
Response.End();
}
```

Comment: Well it worked, I got the PDF download, but when I tried to open it, Adobe Reader told me that the file was corrupt or something. Couldn't read the file. It's more progress than anything else I've seen so far though

Answer (score 1):

You can try develop your solution using [PDFSharp](http://pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/) a very simple pdf library for .net

Comment: ITextSharp is another alternative to look at.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [this](http://moustafa-arafa.blogspot.com/2007/03/export-data-list-to-excel.html) and change the content type to PDF.

Answer (score 0):

This worked out great accept it does not set margins for me despite what I set them on the site. Is there anyways to do this for the Word part of this? Also i find the PDF part does not work.

(The big export post)